# "The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context" when manipulating the result of Bind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a hue value retrieved from a databound gridview control to the backcolour of the text box that is being used to display the value. After editing the ItemTemplate for the relevant column, I've added the following code to take the Hue value from my data, convert it to a colour and then pass that to the BackColor property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" BackColor='<%# GetColourFromHue(int.Parse(Bind("Hue"))) %>' ReadOnly="True" Text='<%# Bind("Hue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context
```

The issue is the fact that I'm wrapping the Bind("Hue") command in more code: `GetColourFromHue(int.Parse(Bind("Hue")))`.

How can I manipulate the value returned by Bind so that I can assign it to the control property?

Comment: There is no way to do so. Bind is not a simple method, it is a specially recognized construct that only works in this form: `<%# Bind("FieldName") %>`. [Blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements) with more details. If you require anything above it, use `Eval` and do two way binding yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrei's comment, I can't use Bind, but I can use Eval. The following works:

```
GetColourFromHue(int.Parse(Eval("Hue").ToString()))
```